# How to include a column or columns from a child Model which belongTo parent Model in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-one

In User Model :

```
public function role(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Roles','id','role_id');

}
```

In Roles Model:

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongTo('App\Model\Users');

}
```

In method :

```
$query = Users::where('id', $id)->get();
```

What i get (in JSON):

```
[{"id":2,"user_name":"hazardgeek","user_email":"nwasuper@example.com","user_phone":"*******","user_password":"*********","remember_token":"*****","role_id":2}]
```

What i actually want:

i want the `role_title` column from the Roles model, not `role_id` from Users table.
Like this,
`......user_password":"thesupernwa","remember_token":null,"role_title":"customer"}]`

How can i achieve this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In User.php Model

```
public function User(){
     protected $appends = ['role_title'];

     public function getRoleTitleAttribute(){
          $role = $this->getRelation('role');
          return !empty($role) ? $this->role->role_title : null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your solution give me an array of roles model within an array of users model. not replacing the role_id column.

Comment: did you added `protected $appends = ['role_title'];` in user.php Model?

Comment: With `$query = Users::where('id', $id)->get();` you can get the role_title. Did you tried this?

Comment: yes i did try that. still cannot have role_title to replace role_id column

Comment: It will not replace the `role_id`, instead it will add and extra property in an array as `role_title` and also it will show the role model. Check your array properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a raw queries to retrieve the right response

```
return DB::table('ctr_user')
            ->select('ctr_user.id AS user_id','user_name','user_email','user_phone','user_password','remember_token','ctr_role.role_title AS title')
            ->rightJoin('ctr_role', 'ctr_role.id','=','ctr_user.role_id')
            ->where('ctr_user.id','=',$id)
            ->get();
```

response return by this raw queries is exactly response I need using Eloquent.

But still how?